# Mock objects and assign them to instance and static variables in a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a class like this:

```
// This class will process the incoming flat files from various data sources
public class FileProcessor {

    private String fileName;//Say filetype_datasource_yyyyMMddHHmmss.dat
    private String fileType;
    private String fileNameWithoutExtension;
    private String fileSource;
    private String timestamp;
    private boolean validFileName;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileProcessor.class);

    public FileProcessor(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void validateFileName() {
        fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf("."));
        String[] fileNameSplit = fileName.split("_");
        fileType = fileNameSplit[0];
        logger.info("File type: " + fileType);
        fileSource = fileNameSplit[1];
        logger.info("File source: " + fileSource);
        timestamp = fileNameSplit[2];
        logger.info("File timestamp: " + timestamp);
        validFileName = validateFileType() &&  validateFileSource() && validateTimestamp();
    }

    private boolean validateFileType() {
        boolean result;
        //Validate as per business rules
        ...
        return result;
    }

    private boolean validateFileSource() {
        boolean result;
        //Validate as per business rules
        ...
        return result;
    }

    private boolean validateTimestamp() {
        boolean result;
        //Validate as per business rules
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

The catch here is that `validateFileName()` uses some instance variables (`fileNameWithoutExtension, fileType, fileSource, timestamp, validFileName`), and a static variable (`logger`).

What is the best way to write JUnit test case mocking the objects that are assigned to the instance and static variables used in the method `validateFileName()`?

I am a beginner to Junit and object mocking, and am open to use any of the mocking frameworks that addresses the concern. Thanks.

Comment: Your class doesn't have any dependency (except maybe logger, but I guess you don't want to test what the class logs). There is nothing to mock. Just create an instance of the class, call the method, and see if it produces the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these variables :

```
 fileNameWithoutExtension, fileType, fileSource, timestamp,
 validFileName
```

are derived data.
You get them from the single dependency of the `FileProcessor` constructor :  `String fileName` parameter.

But even `String fileName` should not mocked. It is not a dependency that you want to isolate. You want that it is a real/normal object as it makes part of the input data of your component.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mock fields as they are all derived from `fileName`, which comes from constructor's argument.

So using JUnit 4 – and assuming you don't need to check what is logged, you could simply do:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

// ... other imports

public class FileProcessorTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // test a valid case
        String file = "filetype_datasource_yyyyMMddHHmmss.dat";
        FileProcessor processor = new FileProcessor(file);
        Assert.assertTrue(processor.validateFileType());
        // ... more assertions

        // test where it should fail
        file = "filetype_invalid_xxx.dat";
        processor = new FileProcessor(file);
        Assert.assertFalse(processor.validateFileType());
        // ... more assertions
    }
}
```